# Is this a submanifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, group-actions

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with an isometric action $\rho : G \to \mathrm{Iso}(M)$ by a compact Lie group $G$. There is a natural extension of $\rho$ to $TM$ given by:
$$\psi : G \times TM \to TM$$
$$\psi(g,p,X) := (\rho(g)p,d\rho(g)X).$$

I would like to know if the set:
$$TM \supset \tilde S := \{(p,X) \in TM : G_X = G_p\}$$ is a submanifold of $TM$, and further, if $\pi : TM \to M$ is the natural projection, then $\pi(\tilde S)$ is a submanifold of $M$.

I tried the following approach:

For each $g\in G$ consider $\eta_g(p,X) \equiv \eta(g,p,X) := d^2_{TM}\left((p,X),\psi(g,p,X)\right).$ Then, one has:
    $$\eta_g^{-1}(0) = \{(p,X) :(\rho(g)p,d\rho(g)X) = (p,X)\}.$$
    So,
    $$\tilde S = \bigcup_{g\in G}\eta_g^{-1}(0). $$

But according to my calculation $0$ is not a regular value of $\eta_g$.

I appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

Thanks to all the answers and comments. I shall change a little the candidate to manifold to another that will be more helpful to me.

I would like to know if one denotes by $\cal H_p$ the orthogonal complement to $T_pG\cdot p$ on the $g$-metric, then the set 
$$S := \{p \in M : \exists X \in \mathcal H_p : G_X = G_p\}$$
is a submanifold of $M$. In fact, this is what I was trying to prove at first.

Comment: Is this a pigeon? ;-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts, I am sorry, what are you asking if it is a pigeon?

Comment: It's a meme, meant in good humour.

Comment: By $G_X$ and $G_p$ you are referring to the vector and point stabilizers, respectively?  I would imagine that generally this is not a manifold without some pretty restrictive assumptions. I'm imagining the action of $G$ degenerating along a stratum, with the stabilized vector space changing. What are you hoping to do with a result like this?

Comment: Dear @RyanBudney, please, consider seeing my edit, as It was suggested on the comments $S$ possibly is a manifold, and that was my original problem. I am working on positive curvature and I need on some step of my argument to be sure that $S$ is a submanifold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition implies that
$$ \tilde S = \bigcup_{p\in M} T_pM^{G_p}. $$
In particular, $\pi(\tilde S) = M$, and $\tilde S$ will be a submanifold of $TM$ iff the dimension of $T_pM^{G_p}$ is the same for all $p\in M$.

$G$ being connected won't necessarily make this happen: Another counterexample is $S^1$ acting by rotation on $S^2$, fixing the north and south poles, $n$ and $s$. $\tilde S$ is then $T(S^2\setminus\{n,s\})\cup \{n,s\}$, and the points $n$ and $s$ do not have neighborhoods homeomorphic to open balls.

**EDIT**

To address the modified question: If $p\in S$, then the orbit $Gp$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $G\times_{G_p} \mathcal H_p$ and we're assuming that $\mathcal H_p^{G_p} \neq 0$. If $q\in \mathcal H_p$ is any point, then $\mathcal H_p^{G_p}$ will be fixed by $G_q$ and still be orthogonal to $Gq$, hence $q$ and every point in $Gq$ will be in $S$. This shows that a neighborhood of $Gp$ is contained in $S$. Thus $S$ is an open submanifold of $M$.

Comment: what if we change a little bit my definition by asking the following: $S = \{p \in M : \exists 0 \neq X \in \mathcal {H}_p \subset T_pM : G_X = G_p\}$? Now I ask if such $S$ is a submanifold of $M$, where $\cal H_p$ is the space $g$-orthogonal to $T_pG\cdot p$.

Comment: My first reaction is that, yes, $S$ will be a submanifold. In fact, an open submanifold: If $p\in S$ then all points in an open neighborhood of $p$ should also satisfy your new condition. Essentially, a neighborhood of $p$ will look like $T_p M$ with the action of $G_p$.

Comment: I have edited the question in order to encompass $S$ to it, it would be extremely helpful if you explain to me your thoughts on why $S$ has a chance to be a submanifold.

Comment: I will accept your answer since I could prove it was true following your comment, I will post the proof on the question.

Answer (score 2):

For the obvious reflection action of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ on $S^1$ this set $\tilde S $ has two singular points at the zero vectors tangent at points $p=(1,0)$ and $q=(-1,0)$.
Then  $\tilde S$ is $T(S^1\setminus \{p,q\}) \cup \{p_0,q_0\}$ where $p_0, q_0$ are zero vectors at $p,q$. This is a connected set and after removing $p_0,q_0$ we obtain a disconnected set. So obviously it is not a manifold because every connected manifold of dimension at least $2$,  remains connected after removing a finite set.

Comment: "every connected manifold remains connected after removing a finite set" -- this is not true for 1-dimensional manifolds. Nonetheless, your example is valid: if $x$ is one of the fixed points of the reflection action, then a neighborhood of $(x,0)\in\tilde S$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ minus the coordinate axes but including the origin, so it cannot be a manifold.

Comment: @ArunDebray  yes thank you but $\tilde S $ is 2 dimensional at generic points. I revise the answer. Thanks again for your correction!

Comment: @AliTaghavi, thank you very much. Do you know if one can restrict some hypothesis in order to obtain a manifold? Or, what kind of structure this set has?

Comment: You are well come. What about if we assume $G$ is connected? I am not sure what is the answer in this case.

Comment: @AliTaghavi, take a look to the other answer and possible on the comments. I changed a little the problem.