# Equivariant vector bundles whose quotient map preserves the stabilizer

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, group-actions, equivariant

Let  $G$  be  a  compact  Lie  group  which  act  on a  manifold  $M$. We fix this  action throughout our  question.

Assume  that $E\to  M$  is  a vector  bundle which has the potential of admitting  a  structure  of  a  $G$-vector  bundle.

> Does  the  total space $E$ admit  an  action by  $G$  such that the new  equivariant  bundle  $p:E\to  M$  satisfies $G_v=G_{p(v)}$, that is the  projection  map  $p$  preserves the stabilizer.

This question is  inspired  by the  following

[Is this a submanifold?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325024/is-this-a-submanifold/325030#325030)

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to asking that the action of $G_x$ on $E_x$ be trivial for every $x\in M$. This implies a necessary condition, that the restriction of $E$ to each orbit $Gx$ is a trivial bundle. But I doubt that's sufficient.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble  very interesting point! What is an example of an equivariant vector bundle which fails the property "triviality on each orbit"?

Comment: One of the simplest would be $S^1\times_{{\mathbb Z}/2} {\mathbb R}$, with ${\mathbb Z}/2$ having the nontrivial action on $\mathbb R$. Thinking of this as a bundle over (the $S^1$-space) $S^1/({\mathbb Z}/2)$, it's the Moebius bundle.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble I think some thing is missing because it is well known that the mobius bundle over circle does not admit a nontrivial equivariant stricture.am i missing some thing?

Comment: $S^1$ here isn't acting on the circle in the usual way: $e^{i\theta}$ rotates by $2\theta$.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble  My  apology  if  my  question is  elementary.  May  you precisely determine what  is the  total  space?(Is  it the  total  space  of  Mobius  bundle)?  what  is the  base  space?(Is  it  S^1)?  what  is  the  group  is  it  $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The group I have in mind acting is all of $S^1$. The total space is $S^1\times\mathbb R$ modulo the action of ${\mathbb Z}/2\mathbb Z$ given by $x(s,v) = (sx^{-1},xv)$ (where ${\mathbb Z}/2\mathbb Z$ has its nontrivial action on $\mathbb R$), with the action of $S^1$ given by $t[s,v] = [ts,v]$. The base space is the orbit $S^1/({\mathbb Z}/2\mathbb Z)$, which we can identify as the circle again, but the action of $S^1$ on this circle is the action I mentioned above, by double the angle. The projection $[s,v] \mapsto [s]$ is the Mobius bundle.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your statement that there are no nontrivial equivariant structures on the Mobius bundle. If you think of the base space as $S^1$ and let $S^1$ act on itself in the usual way, then that action doesn't lift (nor do the restricted actions by subgroups of $S^1$). But if you think of the base space as the orbit $S^1/({\mathbb Z}/2\mathbb Z)$ as above, the action does lift. It may help to think of the unit vector bundle of the Mobius bundle, which is the double cover $S^1\to S^1/({\mathbb Z}/2\mathbb Z)$.